# ionic-native/contacts -- Cannot find name ContactField

Tags: ionic-framework, angular2-components

When trying to create a function [that accesses a users contacts](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/contacts/) in ionic I am getting the following error

[image]

In the app.module I have

```
import { Contacts, Contact, ContactField, ContactName } from '@ionic-native/contacts';

....
...
@NgModule({

..
providers: [
    Contacts,
    Contact,
    ContactField,
    ContactName
]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

also in my contacts component I import

contacts.component.ts

```
import { Contacts, Contact, ContactField, ContactName } from '@ionic-native/contacts';
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This issue has resolved when i update my ionic version of my project.

Do

```
npm install -g ionic@latest
```